# freebsd kernel module - "make" command: unable to locate the kernel source tree. Set SYSDIR to override

Tags: freebsd, kernel-module

I am newbie in freebsd. I installed freebsd on VMware. I want to write first freebsd kernel module. I find this link: [How to write a FreeBSD Kernel Module](https://www.rhyous.com/2011/11/08/how-to-write-a-freebsd-kernel-module/)

But in step3, after **make** command I get:
*unable to locate the kernel source tree. Set SYSDIR to override.*

What is the output of **make** command?
What should I do now?

Comment: Have you tried to **google** this error message? Have you kernel sources installed on your machine (usually under `/usr/src`)?

Comment: Yes, I search, But no success! How can I do it? **sysinstall** command not found!

Comment: So your **actual problem** is "how to install kernel sources", isn't it? Then why do you ask about building the module, if you *know* that this doesn't work without kernel sources?

Comment: I didn't know it! I knew it today and after testing some ways I sent this post. I am a beginner by many problems in this field.

Answer (score 1):

The [FreeBSD handbook](https://www.freebsd.org/doc/handbook/synching.html)  describes how to get the Kernel Source with [svn](https://www.freebsd.org/doc/handbook/svn.html).

**Update** FreeBSD now uses git, so [The handbook](https://docs.freebsd.org/en/books/handbook/mirrors/index.html#git) describes how to sync the source with git

Comment: The link is broken

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, where you want to start is checking out the FreeBSD source.  Like this:

svnlite co http://svn.freebsd.org/base/head

This will create the "head" directory.  Then: move the directory with your modules' source code into head/sys/dev/.  Go do head/sys/modules/, use 'pty' as example (cp -r pty yourmodule), modify head/sys/modules/yourmodule/Makefile (it's self-explanatory, just change the output name and source file names), modify head/sys/modules/Makefile to add "yourmodule" (again, just search for "pty" there, copy, paste, rename).  Voila - you've connected your kernel module to the build in the best possible way; you can now use "make buildkernel installkernel", kgdb(8) will know where the sources for your code are, you have INVARIANTS enabled etc.

Answer (score 0):

Before creating/testing your own module I would suggest to first try to compile a [generic kernel](https://www.freebsd.org/doc/handbook/kernelconfig-building.html), next a custom kernel and only after successfully doing all this, try to start testing your modules. The idea of this is to get familiar with how freebsd build process works and help you implement your modules faster.

This are the basic "fast" steps (skiping `mergemaster`) for doing a full clean upgrade:

1. cd /usr/src
2. svnlite co svn://svn.freebsd.org/base/stable/11 /usr/src
3. make buildworld (if have multiple cores you can try make -j40 buildworld)
4. make kernel (or make -j40 kernel)
5. make installworld (skip the mergemaster -p)
6. yes | make delete-old
7. cp -R /etc /etc.old && cd /usr/src && make distribution DESTDIR=/
8. cd /etc.old && cp group passwd master.passwd /etc && pwd_mkdb /etc/master.passwd
9. reboot
10. yes | make delete-old-libs

After doing all this, you can start to customise you builds by either editing the [/etc/src.conf](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=src.conf&sektion=&n=1) file and the [/etc/make.conf](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?make.conf(5)) in where you can define to compile only your module and therefore make the build process faster, below and example of an `/etc/make.conf` which will only compile `zfs` and `opensolaris` modules besides using a custom kernel [`/usr/src/sys/amd64/conf/TEQUILA`](https://github.com/nbari/freebsd/blob/master/kernels/tequila.kernel) :

```
MODULES_OVERRIDE=zfs opensolaris
KERNCONF=TEQUILA
```

By doing this you can compile/test much faster, you could indeed only do:

```
MODULES_OVERRIDE=mymodule
```

Comment: Is it required to compile the whole kernel if you just want to try creating a new kernel module or can be kernel modules be compiled separately?